# Variance, expectation and probability

Tags: probability

A random variable $X$ has expected value $\mathbb{E}[X] = 3$ and variance $\mbox{Var}[X]=2$.
Is it possible for the probability of $\mathbb{P}(1\leq X \leq 5)$ to be $0.4$?

The problem does not follow any particular distribution, any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

By the [Chebyshev Inequality,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality) if $X$ has mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, then 
$$\Pr(|X-\mu|\ge k\sigma)\le \frac{1}{k^2}.$$
Here $\sigma=\sqrt{2}$. Let $k\sigma=2$. Then $k=\sqrt{2}$. It follows that
$$\Pr(|X-3|\ge 2)\le \frac{1}{2}\lt 0.6.$$

Thus it is not possible to have $\Pr(1\le X\le 5)=0.4$.